# Django Allowed_host issue despite entered in field

Tags: django

I was following this tutorial about [Django 08:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpR1W-NWnp4) integration and I can't access any hosts other than local domains. I have configured the allowed hosts as such:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['test.domains','productivity','127.0.0.1','localhost']
```

I run the Django server using this command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
```

What I am trying to do is to access the Django website using by typing this URL (for example) http://test.domains:8002. For the life of me, I can't seem to get it working as simply as Tony does. I've been on countless thread about allowed_hosts but all of them seems to be solved once you entered the socked in the allowed_host list, and I've also restarted apache 2.

Of note, when I use, for example 0.0.0.0:8002 I see the notification in the terminal about 0.0.0.0 not being part of the allowed domains but when I try any test.domains or productivity there is no ping.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Add the IP of your domain instead of domain name

Answer (score 0):

Add your port number as well like this `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['productivity:8000']` or

you can also just add `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` so it will allow all hosts.